# angularfirebase2 list query returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I must be seriously misunderstanding something with RxJs and AngularFirebase2 because I can't figure out this error.

I have a firebase list that I am querying with a function in a service like so:

```
 returnAuthor(id) {
    this.db.list('/flamelink/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); return data })
}
```

The `console.log(data)` in `returnAuthor` produces the correct data, but `{{ returnAuthor(id) }}` in my template returns `undefined`. Running `returnAuthor` in my component also returns `undefined`.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction here? Do I need to subscribe in the component and not the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method returns undefined because you are not returning a result from the function.
To return a result, your function will look like this

```
returnAuthor(id) {
  return this.db.list('/flamelink/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); return data })
}
```

But returning like that will return a subscription not the data. If you want the data from the subscription, you can declare a variable and set the data returned from the subscription to it. Something like this

*in your class*

```
dataVariable;

    returnAuthor(id) {
      this.db.list('/flamelink/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); this.dataVariable = data })
    }
```

Now the data available from the subscription will be passed onto the `dataVariable` that you can use.

In case you want to pass the data to another method when it arrives, you can call the method in the subscription. Something like this

```
returnAuthor(id) {
   this.db.list('/flamelink/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => { console.log(data); anotherMethod(data); })
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks. I should have caught that I actually wasn't returning anything. I am still confused though. I tried making the function just return the observable like this 
    `returnAuthor(id) {
    return this.db.list('/flamelink/users', ref => 
    ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges()
   }` 
and then I thought I would be able to just use `{{ returnAuthor(id) | async }}` in my template but it just returns null again (even though explicitly subscribing to it and logging the result producing the correct value).

Comment: Since `this.db.list('/flamelink/users', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges()` returns an observable, using `async` pipe should work. I don't know why it wasn't working in your case. Sorry. Please remember to accept the answer if it answered your question